# dojo realtime Punctuate number at thousands dijit.form.NumberTextBox

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I would separate with . every keypress and not only when the user exit from focus of field

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText1" dojoType="dijit.form.NumberTextBox"></xp:inputText>
```

Is possible, if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

See the [tests](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/form/TextBox_types.html). And the [docs](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/form/NumberTextBox#id6). If I understand, you want number formatting, and yes - it is possible.

Comment: Yes this I know...I need in real time execute the formatting code. Now this formatting work only when you exit from the focus of the number field. 

I need to apply the format in real time when the user press every button keyboard without lose focus fields.. 
I hope that now is clear

Comment: I see. I don't think that this is possible. Wouldn't this be confusing(the changing of the text while you type)?